# Flowplayer: How to unbind an event?

Tags: javascript, flowplayer

How do I unbind Flowplayer event, which I have previously set?

```
    flowplayer('player9999').onCuepoint(55000, function() {
        ...
    });
```

Like unbind on click:

```
$('#some').click(function() {
    flowplayer('player9999').onCuepoint().unbind(); // something like this.
});
```

I tried `flowplayer("player9999").removeCuepoints` but I get an error saying *Error: flowplayer("player9999").removeCuepoints is not a function).

I'm using FlowPlayer 3.2.9.

Comment: Each Clip has a `removeCuePoints()` method: http://releases.flowplayer.org/apidoc-latest/org/flowplayer/model/Clip.html#removeCuepoints()

Comment: Error: flowplayer("player9999").removeCuepoints is not a function

Comment: what version of flowplayer are you using ?

Comment: removeCuepoints() is a flash method and not exposed to the javascript API. So you need to call it via Flash maybe by writing a small plugin.

Comment: Could you provide some examples?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement custom logic inside event handler:

```
flowplayer('player9999').onCuepoint(55000, function() {
    if (flag){
         //do something
    }
});
```